# Display the keyboard above the buttons

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard

In the windows phone 7, settings->Email+accounts->create a account, the screen contains two buttons below, 'previous' and 'sign in'. The soft keyboard does not overlap these buttons. I want to implement a similar functionality in my application. I have two buttons at the bottom of the page but these buttons get hidden due to the soft keyboard. Is there any way, where I can show the keyboard above the buttons and application bar buttons are not serving the purpose. Could you please suggest a method as what can be done for this.

Comment: let me just make it clear - the app bar and the app bar buttons are not an option for you?

Comment: nope according to the design, i need to place buttons in the rectangle shape

Answer (score 1):

this is not possbile. The mechanism available to developers (3rd party.. non partner) is using AppBar buttons only.

the default WP code does not use controls available in SDK. Instead the SDK and the additional controls try to replicate functionality / behaviour of native controls used

Comment: Knowledge and experience of doing WP dev for 2 years? If you doubt that, search through the 100k+ apps on store and find one 3rd party app

Comment: Hi Hermit, I wasn't having the go at you, i just would like to have some sort of official confirmation for this line from you: _the default WP code does not use controls available in SDK._

Comment: The basis of that was general conversations with a few people involved with Silverlight toolkit. Performance wise / design wise, you can come close Stock apps but you can't make your apps behave the same way.. more asked question is behaviour of the email viewer